# Protocol: Cannot assign to 'X' in 'Y' in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I just defined a very simple protocol and a a class using generics which can handle this protocol.

In the lines marked with error you will get the error: **"Cannot assign to 'flag' in 'aObj'.**

```
 protocol Flag {
    var flag: Bool {get set}
 }


 class TestFlag<T: Flag>  {

    func toggle(aObj: T) {

        if aObj.flag {
            aObj.flag = false;  // <--- error
        } else {
            aObj.flag = true;   // <--- error
        }
    }
 }
```

Do you have an idea why and what I have to change to fix it?

Comment: Just copy it in a playground to test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID172):

> Function parameters are constants by default. Trying to change the
>   value of a function parameter from within the body of that function
>   results in a compile-time error. This means that you can’t change the
>   value of a parameter by mistake.

In this case, you can add `inout` so that the toggle is persisted beyond your function call:

```
func toggle(inout aObj: T) {           
   if aObj.flag {
      aObj.flag = false;
   else {
      aObj.flag = true;
   }
}
```

You could have also done:

```
func toggle(var aObj: T) { 
}
```

but that might not achieve what you wanted.

Comment: I had the same issue, but in my case, aObj was a property of the class. I needed to do `var aObj = self.aObj; aObj.flag = true`

Answer (score 2):

manojlds answer is correct and therefore I accepted it.

Nevertheless there was a similar answer some days ago with the same solution but with a other argumentation (seems now deleted).

The argumentation was about that the compliler can not know if the protocol is used for a class, a struct or a enum. With Swift, protocols can by applied on all this types. But struct instances use a by-value call and for classes instances (objects) it us a by-reference call.

From my perspective this answer was correct too, because you can solve the problem with a 2nd solution:

```
@objc  
protocol Flag {
    var flag: Bool {get set} 
}
```

Just add the @obj attriute on the protocol. As a result you can use this protocol only for a class which lead to the result only by-refernece calls are allowd. Therefore the compiler don't need anymore the `inout` information.

But I searched for a solution to increase the reuse of the protocol and use now manojlds suggestions.

Comment: You can also do this... protocol Flag: class { ... }